# It extrudes in incorrect directions

Tags: extrude

For some reason, when I try https://youtu.be/GRAzuKlpEsg?t=222  AT 3:44, it extrudes one side of the grenade in one direction and the other side in the other direction, however on the video, 3:44 it extrudes proportionally, in all directions at once, can someone help with this?

I will attach image of what I have[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe select all and press Shift N to recalculate the normals?

Comment: It worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your faces are inverted, you need to recalculate the normals: Select all in *Edit* mode (<kbd>A</kbd>) and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.